# The first/last/next/only to V or Ving

Tags: word-usage

Recently, I'm quite confused about the usage of the first(second,third……)/next/last/only.

> He was the first ____ the school in that area.
>
> (A)to open (B) opening

The answer is (A).

But,I remember the first(second,third……)/next/last/only can be used with the relative pronoun "that".

> For example,he was the first person "that" opened the school in that area.

Also,I remember relative pronoun can be deleted with the verb it brings turning into ving or vpp.

Therefore,in my mind,the sentence"He was the first opening the school in that area" can make sense.

So,what do you think?and why？or is it just an idiom？

Comment: "He was the first **person** opening ..." is fine, but if you omit 'person' and expect 'first' to act as a pronoun, you create a garden path because 'the first opening' looks like a noun phrase  (!"He was the first opening").

Comment: It feels odd to use 'that' in reference to a person. 'The first parcel that arrived was from Mary" is OK, but "The first person who..." would be better.

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @AmI Tanks for your answer. Is seems to me you are right. Thus, I appreciate it very much.：)

Comment: @KateBunting https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/146081-ordinal-number-before-relative-pronouns

Comment: @KateBunting pardon me,but my textbook and some other grammatical books indicate the same usage as what the website I offer is about.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree with anything it says on your website. However, I couldn't find any mention of 'first' etc. being used of a _person_ rather than a thing.

Comment: @Changyo - English does prefer using 'who' when relativising a person, but using 'that' or 'which' has an advantage in that we use 'that' for restrictions and 'which' for adjuncts.  With 'who' this distinction is entirely dependent on whether a comma (pause) is used before the relative pronoun.

Comment: @KateBunting Although I think what you replied was out of the question,I still look up Cambridge to find this definition. One definition of "first" is as the noun「the first person or thing to do or be something, or the first person or thing mentioned:
Example:
[ + to infinitive ] She was one of the first to arrive.」

Comment: @AmI sorry,but what is your answer to？xddd

Comment: @Changyo - 'first' can be used like a [pro]noun, and its antecedent can be a person, but 'first' can also be an adjective, and any v-ing can be a noun (gerund), so the parse gets confusing: ("She was the first arriving").  One fix is to insert another [pro]noun: "She was the first **one** arriving."

Comment: @AmI yeah,I know it. Actually,I have no problem with your answer and the topic of this post is solved with your answer.xd Thus, thanks your quite useful help again.：) You do help me to clarify why ving in the sentence will be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{combined my comments into an answer: xDD}

"He was the first **person** opening ..." is fine, but if you omit 'person' and expect 'first' to act as a pronoun, you create a garden path because 'the first opening' looks like a noun phrase (!"He was the first opening").

Yes, you can use a relative pronoun and say "He was the first that opened ..." or "He was the first that was opening ...", but English does prefer using 'who' when relativising a person. Using 'that' or 'which' has an advantage in that we use 'that' for restrictions and 'which' for adjuncts. With 'who' this distinction is entirely dependent on whether a comma (pause) is used before the relative pronoun.

To reiterate, 'First' can be used like a [pro]noun, and its antecedent can be a person, but 'first' can also be an adjective, and any v-ing can be a noun (gerund), so the parse gets confusing: ("She was the first arriving"). One fix is to insert another [pro]noun: "She was the first **one** arriving", "He was the first **one** opening ..."

Comment: Well……I really appreciate your answer after combination.